# DBC Exercise 9 - Calculate the Missing Number

Tags: ruby

#### Exercise 9 - 45 minutes

You have been given a list of sequential numbers from 1 to 10,000, but they are all out of order; furthermore, 1 number is missing from the list. The goal is to find which number is missing.Write out in plain English your strategy for solving this problem. Be as concise as possible.

Write Ruby code that takes this list of numbers as an argument, and returns the missing number.

Answer (score 0):

My initial impression is some sort of sort function will help me put the array into order, but then I reread the problem and its not asking for a sorted sequence, it's asking for a missing number. The next step to consider is how do you determine a number that is the next sequence and I think of the 99 bottles challenge in Chris Pine's book and realize that that "n + 1"or "n - 1" will be a part of the solution as will a 'range statement' that begins with 1 and ends with 10,000 (1..10,000).

I next think about indexing and that I'll need to loop through the range using #upto or #each to determine the missing number as well as some sort of conditional statement that allows me to return the missing value. I'll be defining a method "missing_number" but what is the input?

Is it an array? Or is it a range? I am going to go with array since most of the time arrays are unsorted and when I test it I'll define the input as a range.

After doing a bit of research I came across a strategy that indicated the key step would be to sum all of the numbers in the array and subtract the

difference from the sum of the given range. This makes a lot of sense as a good approach because you are dealing with a constant value, so I selected this approach
to inform the code.

```
def missing_number(array)
  grand_sum = (array.length + 1) * (array.length + 2) / 2
  sum = 0
  array.each {|n| sum += n}
  grand_sum - sum
end

x=(1..10000).to_a
x.delete rand(10000)
puts missing_number(x)
```

Comment: better write `grand_sum - array.reduce(:+)`.